# Java 1.7 - Cloning object and lists inside him

Tags: java, arraylist, clone

I was trying to cloning object that has, inside him, lists of object.
I want to clone the entire object, also his lists.

I explain my self:

I have this:

```
public class MyObject implements Cloneable{
    private long a;
    private List<AnotherObject> listA;
    private List<AnotherObject> listB;

    //getter and setter methods;

    @Override
    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }
}
```

I create an instance of him:

```
MyObject original = new MyObject();
```

And suppose that we have used this object, therefore we loaded the lists inside him.

Now, I want to clone it.

I done this, thinking it was enough

```
MyObject clone = (MyObject) original.clone();
```

But, inspecting the original and cloned object in debug mode I saw that their lists refer to the same memory area.

In fact, changing an element of listA of the original object this modification  is also visible in the cloned object!

To resolve it I done:

```
clone.setListA(new ArrayList<AnotherObject>(original.getListA());
```

It's a good solution?

Comment: You need to clone the list, yes, if not you will use the same references, so basicly the same list. But you might want to clone the instance in the lists too.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you'd better implement deep cloning in MyObject#clone() method or you can use some deep cloning library, for example, there is [cloning](https://github.com/kostaskougios/cloning/) and [Kryo](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo#copyingcloning).

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of cloning in Java: Shallow cloning and Deep cloning. This one is shallow cloning.

Please refer below article that shows how to implement deep cloning:
http://www.jusfortechies.com/java/core-java/deepcopy_and_shallowcopy.php